# How to move a specific customer data from one Postgres RDS to another

Tags: sql, postgresql, migration, amazon-rds, database-migration

I'm using a Postgres DB, in which I have database "a" with a schema per customer id.
I sometimes need to move a single customer schema **data** to another RDS. A single schema can weigh up to 1TB.

I looked at [pg_transport](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/PostgreSQL.TransportableDB.html) extension, but as far as I see in the docs, it only includes an option to migrate an entire database.
My question is -
1. Is there a way around this limitation other than copying the entire database and deleting all the schemas but the 1 I wanted?
2. Are there any other tools that will cover this use-case better?

Comment: is pg_dump / pg_restore an option? that can be done per db, schema, table, or set of any of the above.

Comment: If you can access the source and destination database servers from the same EC2 instance, then you could pipe the output of `pg_dump` to the input of `psql` on the destination database. Something like: `pg_dump <source table> | psql -h <target>`

Comment: This is indeed an option, but I'm looking for something more optimized, as pg_dump & restore can take a long time for such DB size

Answer (score 1):

There are many approaches in AWS where you can load the data from one RDS to another,

- AWS Glue (ETL tool which allows you the load the data as well as enables you to transform the data if required)
- Lambda (You can have a simple lambda script in Python/Java/Scala to load the data)
- AWS Data Pipeline

You can also use other open source ETL tools like talend, where you can develop the process and place the code in EC2 for execution

AWS Glue is preferable, you can transform as well as schedule the process